# Azure CLI - invalid .NET runtime version

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli

Our pipeline on Azure DevOps which has been working suddenly fails when running the Azure CLI command:

> az functionapp config set name "appname" --resource-group "groupname" --slot "slot" --net-framework-version v7.0

The error it produces is

> *Invalid version:  for runtime dotnet-isolated and os windows. Supported versions for runtime dotnet-isolated and os windows are: ['.4.8', '8', '7', '6']. Run 'az functionapp list-runtimes' for more details on supported runtimes.*

Our azure function is version 4 running on .NET Core 7.0

Anyone know why all of a sudden it gives this warning? I've tried to use v7, 7.0 and 7 and they all produce the same warning.

Our Azure CLI version is 2.57.0.  I check its [release version page](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/blob/main/docs-ref-conceptual/release-notes-azure-cli.md) and I see nothing mentioned about .NET framework value being changed.

Comment: Have you tried running az functionapp list-runtimes in your pipeline to see what values the cli will allow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier I set the Function **`.NET Version to 7 Isolated`**, Now I set this to **`.NET 8 Isolated`** via Azure DevOps pipeline **`Azure CLI`** task like below:-

[image]

***Azure CLI task:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (xxxx5-f598-xx6xxxx-xxxxa7)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az functionapp config set --name "valleyfunc765" --resource-group "silconrg62" --net-framework-version 8'
```

***Output:-***

[image]

**`.NET 8 Isolated`** updated successfully:-

[image]

**`.NET 8 Isolated`** was updated successfully, Refer below:-

The warning message was present in the **`Devops console`** but you can ignore this warning as it looks like a transient issue with **`AzureCLI@2`** Devops task, The same warning did not get popped when I ran the same command in my Local command prompt:-

Devops warning, But still the code ran successfully:-

[image]

> WARNING: Invalid version: for runtime dotnet-isolated and os windows. Supported versions for runtime dotnet-isolated and os windows are: ['.4.8', '8', '7', '6']. Run 'az functionapp list-runtimes' for more details on supported runtimes.

Local command prompt output:-

***Command:-***

```bash
az functionapp config set --name "siliconnet7iso" --resource-group "siliconRG" --net-framework-version 8
```

[image]

[image]

I also ran a command to list all the runtime, It also showed .NET Version - 7 and Isolated in the list:-

**Command:-**

```bash
az functionapp list-runtimes --os windows
```

**Output:-**

[image]

I have raised a [BUG request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-yaml-schema/issues/308) on the Azure DevOps console warning even when the code is running successfully you can keep an eye on it

**References:-**

[az functionapp config | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-set)

[az functionapp | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-list-runtimes)

Comment: @Fylix  Refer the [Bug request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-yaml-schema/issues/308) on the warning thats getting printed in devops console

Comment: Yup, the bug is the core _FunctionAppStackRuntimeHelper which produces ValidationError exception on these values. This new warning is added because they added in the check_language_runtime() couple of weeks ago whenever you use cli to update your function app.    https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/commit/4e551ab71c665b412622f98f335fa301b2ece414

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @SiddheshDesai. This is just a warning not an error, it can be executed successfully, you can ignore the message.

On DevOps pipeline(checked on both ubuntu-latest and windows-latest agent), the Azure-ClI version is `2.57.0`.

[image]

I installed the [same version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) Azure CLI, and run the same command, can reproduce the same on **local machine**:

[image]

With Previous Azure CLI version 2.55, it doesn't report the warning message.

[image]

The warning message should be caused by the latest azure-CLI version 2.57

Comment: I think you are both correct, it looks like the following code is added 3 weeks ago.  Which makes sense that we don't see this in CLI 2.55.0

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/87dec2c86a39da9cc056697a92a234da86c97646/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py#L409